# Scala - Extends multi class with parameters

Tags: scala, traits

I would like to make some classes like this.

```
class A(val a1: String) {
    def message() = println(a1)
}
class B(val b1: String) {
    def doB() = println(b1)
}
class C(val c1: String) {
    def something() = println(c1)
}
class AB(val a: String, val b: String) extends A(a) with B(b) {
    //                                               ^error
}
class AC..
class BC..
```

I tried to use trait but since trait cannot have any parameter, It made error too. How should I do to make somthing like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gives you error because `trait` doesn't have constructor. But you can change it to the `trait` parameters like this;

```
class A(val a1: String) {
  def message() = println(a1)
}

trait B {

  def b: String

  def doB() = println(b)
}

class AB(val a: String, val b: String) extends A(a) with B {
  //this should work                                               
}
```

Comment: Then do I need to set 'b' value somewhere inside AB class?

Comment: As you see second parameter is b: String, it means we're overriding b in trait. So no need to set if you are passing through constructor in AB